# Unexpected tlmgr behaviour

Tags: tlmgr, texlive-2019, texlive-2020

I have the following unexpected behaviour when I run `tlmgr`

- Running `tlmgr --version` tells me I'm running TeX Live 2020, namely the output is:

```
tlmgr revision 57119 (2020-12-13 00:40:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2020
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020
```

- Running  `sudo tlmgr --gui` tells me I'm running TeX Live *2019* (‽), in particular:

```
tlmgr revision 53568 (2020-01-27 19:20:16 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019
```

- Running `sudo su` and then `tlmgr --gui` gives me again TeX Live 2020, with output:

```
tlmgr revision 57119 (2020-12-13 00:40:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2020
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020
```

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

I tried removing `/usr/share/texlive` hoping that if tlmgr won't find it it would go about to search for `/usr/local/texlive/2020`, but no luck.

It should be noted that I installed texlive 2020 on a fresh system, i.e. I never ever installed texlive 2019, which makes this behaviour even more surprising.

Comment: With just `sudo` you don't export the user's environment, so the shell uses the default path. Apparently you have also installed the distribution provided TeX Live. I guess you're on a Debian based GNU/Linux system. AFAIR, `sudo -e` exports the environment.

Comment: I am indeed on a Debian based Linux system. I tried to be careful not to install anything of the distribution provided TeX Live, but apparently I failed. Can I remove all such instances of TeX Live 2019, without removing TeX Live2020 or will it mess things up more?

Comment: I'd leave it alone. There are recipes to make the distribution think that TeX Live is installed via `dpkg`, but if you don't have disk space constraints having it shouldn't be a big problem, so long as the default `PATH` is set up to have `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/<arch>` at the beginning or, at least, before `/usr/bin`/.

Comment: I see, thanks! There are more to resolve (concerning fonts and font maps, that might have accidentally gone only to the 2019 edition of TeX Live) but these will concern a separate question if I don't manage them myself.